# elasticsearch changing path.logs and/or path.data - fails to start

Tags: elasticsearch

Here's my config

```
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
path.data: /mulelogs/elasticsearch
path.logs: /mulelogs/elasticsearch
```

When I restart ElasticSearch this is what I get:

```
 elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-01-25 06:33:40 UTC; 9s ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
  Process: 22213 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Des.pidfile=${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.path.home=${ES_HOME} -Des.default.path.logs=${LOG_DIR} -Des.default.path.data=${DATA_DIR} -Des.default.path.conf=${CONF_DIR} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 22212 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch-systemd-pre-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22213 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

elasticsearch[22213]: at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromStream(Settings.java:1074)
elasticsearch[22213]: at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings$Builder.loadFromPath(Settings.java:1061)
elasticsearch[22213]: at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareEnvironment(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:88)
elasticsearch[22213]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialSettings(Bootstrap.java:217)
elasticsearch[22213]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:256)
elasticsearch[22213]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:35)
elasticsearch[22213]: Refer to the log for complete error details.
systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

The path is an attached volume which is accessible via **/mulelogs/**

```
drwxrwxrwx.  4 root          root           4096 Jan 25 05:11 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 18 root          root           4096 Jan 25 06:24 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  4 elasticsearch elasticsearch  4096 Jan 25 05:21 elasticsearch
drwxrwxrwx.  2 root          root          16384 Jan 20 01:20 lost+found
```

I tried chown and chmod just to see if the permission is the problem, but it still didn't work.

How do I fix this?

Thanks in ad

**Notes:**

- OS: CentOS 7
- ElasticSearch : 2.1
- I have installed ELK following this steps:
  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-centos-7

Comment: check whether path is accessible (means permission), or try re-installing service

Comment: I have tried that in a fresh box, it still the same issue. The permission is already set to 777, and ownership is set to elasticsearch

Comment: if you have error in configuration file, the instance won't start

Comment: I'm aware that there could be something wrong in the config or somewhere in the setup, that's why it won't start. And based on the details above, how do I find it out?


Note: I'm new to ElasticSearch, and is just starting to experiment with it. Plus, its working as per the guide I followed, until I change the values of **path.data** and **path.logs**

Answer (score 0):

try changing the paths

path.data: /mulelogs/elasticsearch
path.logs: /mulelogs/elasticsearch

to absolute

Answer (score 0):

I had a fresh install and had the same error.

Check if you have a folder in your **path.data** directory with the name of your cluster. If yes, try to delete it (if possible and you don't loose data).

After deleting this and restarting the service it went ok (another folder called **nodes** was created)

Answer (score 0):

1. change mode to 777 for new lib and log directories and files.
2. check the log file, if it shows error message like:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: detected index data in
>   default.path.data [/var/lib/elasticsearch] where there should not be
>   any; check the logs for details

as the above error, you have to delete the nodes directory in old lib folder. (Backup first, index data will be gone.)