# can not change path.data in elasticsearch config

Tags: elasticsearch, configure

I can not change local ES index location - can not modify path.data .

That's probably some elementary mistake, but I am stuck and greatly appreciate any assistance.

So:
Fresh local installation of ES 7.8.1 under Centos 7, everything runs correctly, if no changes were done in elasticsearch.yml:
But if I try change elasticsearch.yml:

```
# path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch'
path.data: /run/media/admin/bvv2/elasticsearch/
```

(i.e. try to point to external disk), I get after systemctl start elasticsearch:

```
Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

where in "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" :

```
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-08-17 16:23:16 MSK; 5min ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co
  Process: 12951 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 12951 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd-entrypoint[12951]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd-entrypoint[12951]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd-entrypoint[12951]: at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd-entrypoint[12951]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126)
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd-entrypoint[12951]: at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd-entrypoint[12951]: For complete error details, refer to the log at /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd[1]: Unit elasticsearch.service entered failed state.
Aug 17 16:23:16 bvvcomp systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service failed.
```

And in journalctl-xe:

```
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp NetworkManager[1112]: <info>  [1597670960.1568] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp NetworkManager[1112]: <info>  [1597670960.1569] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   lease time 25200
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp NetworkManager[1112]: <info>  [1597670960.1569] dhcp4 (wlp2s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp NetworkManager[1112]: <info>  [1597670960.1569] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> bound
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp dbus[904]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp dhclient[1325]: bound to 192.168.1.141 -- renewal in 12352 seconds.
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp dbus[904]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp nm-dispatcher[13569]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp2s0]: new request (4 scripts)
Aug 17 16:29:20 bvvcomp nm-dispatcher[13569]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [wlp2s0]: start running ordered scripts...
```

Unfortunately, these advice did not help:

[How to move elasticsearch data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143926/how-to-move-elasticsearch-data-directory)  ;

[elasticsearch changing path.logs and/or path.data - fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986526/elasticsearch-changing-path-logs-and-or-path-data-fails-to-start)  ;

[Elasticsearch after change path.data, unable to access 'default.path.data'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46860229/elasticsearch-after-change-path-data-unable-to-access-default-path-data)  ;

thats probably new issue, version 7.x bounded ?

Thank you

Update 1 - error log (/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log):

```
[2020-08-18T01:30:00,000][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] [bvvcomp] triggering scheduled [ML] maintenance tasks
[2020-08-18T01:30:00,014][INFO ][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [bvvcomp] Deleting expired data
[2020-08-18T01:30:00,052][INFO ][o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction] [bvvcomp] Completed deletion of expired ML data
[2020-08-18T01:30:00,053][INFO ][o.e.x.m.MlDailyMaintenanceService] [bvvcomp] Successfully completed [ML] maintenance tasks
[2020-08-18T04:30:00,017][INFO ][o.e.x.s.SnapshotRetentionTask] [bvvcomp] starting SLM retention snapshot cleanup task
[2020-08-18T04:30:00,025][INFO ][o.e.x.s.SnapshotRetentionTask] [bvvcomp] there are no repositories to fetch, SLM retention snapshot cleanup task complete
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,457][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [bvvcomp] stopping ...
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,482][INFO ][o.e.x.w.WatcherService   ] [bvvcomp] stopping watch service, reason [shutdown initiated]
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,483][INFO ][o.e.x.w.WatcherLifeCycleService] [bvvcomp] watcher has stopped and shutdown
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,495][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [bvvcomp] [controller/21903] [Main.cc@155] ML controller exiting
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,497][INFO ][o.e.x.m.p.NativeController] [bvvcomp] Native controller process has stopped - no new native processes can be started
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,540][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [bvvcomp] stopped
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,541][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [bvvcomp] closing ...
[2020-08-18T05:27:08,585][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [bvvcomp] closed
[2020-08-18T05:27:19,077][ERROR][o.e.b.Bootstrap          ] [bvvcomp] Exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to access 'path.data' (/run/media/admin/bvv2/elasticsearch)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.addFilePermissions(Security.java:297) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.createPermissions(Security.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.configure(Security.java:121) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:222) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393) [elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170) [elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161) [elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) [elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127) [elasticsearch-cli-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-cli-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126) [elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92) [elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /run/media/admin/bvv2
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:313) ~[?:?]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:766) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Security.ensureDirectoryExists(Security.java:389) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.FilePermissionUtils.addDirectoryPath(FilePermissionUtils.java:68) ~[elasticsearch-7.8.1.jar:7.8.1]
    ... 12 more
```

Permissions:

```
ls -l /run/media/admin/bvv2
drwxrwsrwx  3 elasticsearch elasticsearch    4096 Aug 17 17:26 elasticsearch
```

```
ls -l /run/media/admin
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 11 admin admin 4096 Aug 17 13:22 bvv2
```

Comment: Can you please share the error log from the elastic log file.

Comment: Thank you. I added + permissions. admin is a non-root user

Comment: Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: unfortunately not - Java mistakes, probably, prevent smooth run. Or, maybe, some other mistake - I do not understand, what else to do.

Comment: After changing the directory permission are you still getting same error in log?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar error and it was caused by incorrect parent directory permissions.

One of the parent directory doesn't allow other unix users to access the directory, more specifically the directory's permission is `drwx--x---+`. Elasticsearch started after change the permission to `drwx--x--x+`(chmod 711). You can also try it.